# OSX semop does not queue processes

Tags: c++, macos, semaphore

I have recently developed a test project in C++ to learn mutual exclusion.

I've created two wraper functions:

```
void Semaphore::semaphore_await(int sem_cluster_id, unsigned short which) //semaphore_p
{
    int zmien_sem;
    sembuf bufor_sem;
    bufor_sem.sem_num = which;
    bufor_sem.sem_op = -1;
    bufor_sem.sem_flg = SEM_UNDO;
    zmien_sem = semop(sem_cluster_id, &bufor_sem, 1);
    if (zmien_sem == -1) {
        printf("Nie moglem zamknac semafora.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    } else {
//        printf("Semafor S%d zostal zamkniety.\n", which);
    }
}

void Semaphore::semaphore_unlock(int semid, unsigned short which) //semaphore_v
{
    int zmien_sem;
    sembuf bufor_sem;
    bufor_sem.sem_num = which;
    bufor_sem.sem_op = 1;
    bufor_sem.sem_flg = SEM_UNDO;
    zmien_sem = semop(semid, &bufor_sem, 1);
    if (zmien_sem == -1) {
        printf("Nie moglem otworzyc semafora.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    } else {
//        printf("Semafor S%d zostal otwarty.\n", which);
    }
}
```

I spawned few processes to compete over the resource and the have following bodies:

```
void critical_section(int semid, unsigned short semaphor_number){
    Semaphore::semaphore_await(semid, semaphor_number);
    std::cout<<"I am process:"<<getpid()<<" and I am in critical section!"<<std::endl;
//    sleep(1);
    Semaphore::semaphore_unlock(semid, semaphor_number);
}
```

And the problem is that I can't reproduce mutual exclusion phenomena. Once a single prcoess gets into the section it doesn't let another process to the section, but most of the time same process executes critical section...

```
I am process:32339 and I am in critical section!
I am process:32346 and I am in critical section!
I am process:32346 and I am in critical section!
I am process:32346 and I am in critical section!
I am process:32346 and I am in critical section!
I am process:32346 and I am in critical section!
I am process:32346 and I am in critical section!
I am process:32346 and I am in critical section!
I am process:32346 and I am in critical section!
I am process:32346 and I am in critical section!
I am process:32346 and I am in critical section!
I am process:32341 and I am in critical section!
I am process:32341 and I am in critical section!
```

And what is even more worriyng under Linux platform such as Manjaro or Ubuntu it works perfectly fine.

Comment: You say you "can't reproduce mutual exclusion", but it sounds like you are doing just that (although your log output is not sufficient to prove that). When you release or unlock a semaphore, there's no guarantee what other waiting process wakes up and acquires the semaphore. You're only guaranteed that just a single process acquires the semaphore. It's not guaranteed to be a fair or round-robin scheduling. If the same process loops around and immediately attempts to acquire the semaphore again, it may be the one that succeeds (perhaps because it's already awake and running).

Comment: @KenThomases Tell it to my teacher XD I secretly hoped that there is a flag to regulate such behavior.